# Why is MATLAB reporting my variable uninitialized?

Tags: oop, matlab

I made a class and in one of its methods I needed to calculate the distance between two points. So I wrote an ordinary function named "remoteness" to do this for me.

#### Compilation Error:

> At compilation, "remoteness" was
>   determined to be a variable and this
>   variable is uninitialized. 
>   "remoteness" is also a function name
>   and previous versions of MATLAB would
>   have called the function.

However, MATLAB 7 forbids the use of the same name in the same context as both a function and a variable.

> Error in ==> TRobot>TRobot.makeVisibilityGraph at 58
>       obj.visiblityGraph(k,k+1) = remoteness(:,obj.VGVertices(k),obj.VGVertices(:,k+1));

I thought the name `remoteness` might be a name of another function, but when I changed its name to `kamran` the error persisted. It should be noted that I can use the `kamran` function (or `remoteness`) in the command line without any problem.

#### Command line example:

```
>> kamran([0,0],[3,4])

ans = 5
```

The code of the `kamran` function is in a separate m file.

#### Code for `kamran` function:

```
function dist = kamran(v1,v2)
    dist = sqrt(    (v1(1) - v2(1)) ^2  + (v1(2) - v2(2)) ^2   );
```

#### Code example for how `kamran` function is used:

```
function obj = makeVisibilityGraph(obj)
          verticesNumber = 0; 
          for num = 1: size(obj.staticObstacle,2)
              verticesNumber = verticesNumber + size(obj.staticObstacle(num).polygon,2);
          end
          % in the below line, 2 is for start and goal vertices
           obj.visibilityGraph = ones(2 + size(obj.VGVertices,2)) * Inf;
           for j=1 : size(obj.staticObstacle,2)
              index = size(obj.VGVertices,2);
              obj.VGVertices = [obj.VGVertices, obj.staticObstacle(j).polygon];
              obj.labelVGVertices = [obj.labelVGVertices, ones(1,size(obj.staticObstacle(j).polygon,2))* j ];
              for k = index+1 : (size(obj.VGVertices,2)-1)
                  obj.visiblityGraph(k,k+1) = kamran(:,obj.VGVertices(k),obj.VGVertices(:,k+1));
              end
%             as the first and last point of a polygon are visible to each
%             other, so set them visible to each other
              obj.visibilityGraph(index+1,size(obj.VGVertices,2)) = ...
                               kamran( obj.VGVertices(:,index+1), obj.VGVertices(:,size(obj.VGVertices,2)));
           end     


end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use kamran as an array:

```
 kamran(:,obj.VGVertices(k),obj.VGVertices(:,k+1));
```

Notice the first parameter ":"?

I would bet MATLAB assumes that kamran (as called here) should be a 3-dimensional array, and you are trying to select the subset containing

```
kamran(all-of-first-index, Nth-of-second, Mth-of-third)
```

The second invocation of kamran looks right:

```
kamran( obj.VGVertices(:,index+1), obj.VGVertices(:,size(obj.VGVertices,2))
```

Comment: +1 Good catch! This is most likely the source of the error. I only noticed the second call to kamran and couldn't see the problem.

Comment: Hah.  I was on the right track but didn't know what the syntax meant.  Good explanation, Jukka.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know MATLAB but I notice on this line, you are running kamran with what looks like 3 arguments.  In all other cases, it is executed with 2 arguments.  Maybe there is something to that?

```
  kamran(:,obj.VGVertices(k),obj.VGVertices(:,k+1));
```